# Perl: Sorting the values of a hash and putting the result in a new hash where the keys are position in ranking

Tags: perl, sorting, ranking

I have the following structure, %hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
           1 => 5,
           3 => 1,
           2 => 4,
           4 => 9,

        };
```

The keys of this hash represent id and the values represent number of access: **id => number of access**

I want to sort this using the number of access, in descending order, and store it in another hash. But I want the values to be the id this time. The keys should be the position in the ranking: **position in raking (from 1 to n) => id**

In this particular case:

```
$VAR2 = {
           1 => 4,
           2 => 1,
           3 => 2,
           4 => 3,
        };
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sort in a foreach loop.

```
my %hash = (
1 => 5,
3 => 1,
2 => 4,
4 => 9,
);

my %hash2;
my $count = 1;
foreach my $key(sort{$hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a}} keys %hash){
    $hash2{$count++} = $key;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%hash2);
```

OR

You can use map to do the looping as David mentioned. I added foreach for simplicity.

```
my %hash2 = map {$count++ => $_} sort{$hash{$b} <=> $hash{$a}} keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code sorts the keys (ids) based on their respective values, and then maps those keys to a ranking.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %old_hash = (
  1 => 5,
  3 => 1,
  2 => 4,
  4 => 9,
);

my $rank = 1;

my %new_hash
  = map  { $rank++ => $_ }
    sort { $old_hash{$b} <=> $old_hash{$a} }
    keys %old_hash;

print Dumper \%new_hash;
```

It's easiest to understand if you read the map/sort/keys construct backwards:

First, list all the keys, second, sort them by the values they index, third, map out a new hash where keys are the current rank, and values are the associated ID.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the ids, so it's going to look like the following:

```
my @ids_by_desc_access =
   sort { ... }
      keys(%accesses_by_id);
```

You want them sorted by descending number of accesses, so we add that comparison:

```
my @ids_by_desc_access =
   sort { $accesses_by_id{$b} <=> $accesses_by_id{$a} }
      keys(%accesses_by_id);
```

Finally, you oddly want to use a hash as an array.

```
my %ids_by_desc_access =
   map { $_+1 => $ids_by_desc_access[$_] }
      0..$#ids_by_desc_access;
```

Comment: I typed this immediately after the question was posted, far before the first answer, but then I suffered a computer breakdown. Since it's a good answer, I figured I'd post it anyway.

Comment: or just `my %ids_by_desc_access; @ids_by_desc_access{1..keys %access_by_id} = sort { $access_by_id{$b} <=> $access_by_id{$a} } keys %access_by_id;`

Comment: @ysth, It can be made into one line, but I was teaching the process of finding the answer rather than just giving the answer. But thanks for the code.